# Linear Regression in R - coef Function

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `coef` function in r, and I need to know how to use this function to extract columns from a dataset. I tried `coef(rain$spring, rain$autumn)` but it returned a message saying I could not use `$`.  The dataset is rain, the variables are spring and autumn. There is another dataset spring so I cannot simply attach the two variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example . Also this question is not related to rstudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the help page before you post a question. `?coef` says that:

> coef is a generic function which extracts model coefficients from
>   objects returned by modeling functions

Therefore, you need to run a linear model using `lm()` on your data-set, then extract the coefficients from the *model*:

```
coef(lm(...))
```